# Mysql compressed backup. Creating zero byte empty file

Tags: mysql, gzip

```
$command = 'mysqldump.exe -u '.$username.' '.$database . '  > '.$location.'\\'.$filename;
system($command);
```

this can create sql file correctly.

Now i'm trying to create compressed backup.

```
$filename = "xyz.sql.gz";
$command = 'mysqldump.exe -u '.$username.' '.$database . ' |gzip > '.$location.'\\'.$filename;
system($command);
```

This is creating a gz file with zero byte size.

please help, where im am doing wrong.

I didnot put -p[password] as the user i used is without password.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste the raw command without the php.

Comment: Actually I'm using a batch file
CLS
C:
cd/
cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\
mysqldump.exe -u root soncology  > C:\wamp\www\MedicalHistory\system\soncology.sql
above code is working perfect for sql file.
now i want compressed backup using this batch file. what r the changes i should make.
thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing Gzip application on windows? or is it in PATH or in same directory than script?

Comment: Thanks for response. I am using WAMP. From wamp export menu I can backup gzip compressed dump. so gzip should be on my windows. Do I need to install it separate?

Comment: Other applications can use gzip as zipping format. Open cmd.exe and try gzip, might be that you need to install it or something equivalent. I do not know what WAMP contains.

Comment: Solved. yeah. I had to copied to gzip.exe to my php folder.